# Get attachment thumbnail - Gmail API

Tags: thumbnails, google-drive-api, gmail-api

I'm trying to find a way to get attachments thumbnails from messages on Gmail.
I understand that Gmail is now directly connected with Drive and that thumbnails are automatically created and stored on Drive but I couldn't find a way to get them via Gmail and Drive API.
Does Google allow access to this data at all?

I noticed that When opening a message on Gmail (Web interface), the request for the attachment thumbnail is:

```
Remote Address:[Some IP Address]
Request URL:https://drive.google.com/viewerng/thumb?[Some Token]&ck=gmail&w=800&p=card
Request Method:GET
```

This is what lead me to believe all thumbnail images are stored on Drive and so getting the thumbnail must be possible somehow.

Any information will be helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is currently possibly using either the gmail or drive APIs.  Sorry!

Comment: With Drive API it is possible to download thumbnails for files stored within Drive and because Gmail is directly related to Drive it is most probable that it is possible to accomplish somehow don't you think? More over, I can't imagine a reason why Google will block this from developers who are building email apps with the new Gmail API.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably figure it out with some effort, but I found it was easier to write the code to generate the thumbnail myself (it takes longer to retrieve the attachment from gmail api than it does to thumbnail it), as I already had a thumbnailer service available, based on OutsideIn (but you could also do it with Microsoft IFilter).

The URL (modified to protect my document) requested over the network looks like this, hardly usable:

```
https://drive.google.com/viewerng/thumb?ds=AAvoAMVZJwEtaA-FdJWOt6dp0Gkcit2q2Q58Shh87xwyv0wJOMRqa7AOtkn_n7relBlioc4gjAwSi0g5c2G2-GRbVDwLfIiShR7hSY70_vz14AGva6cvTpNy2aVS1rfDXj1ClDXdcN76wtB8r5Lr8wX1nTRoq-HAX4ufjVg4TXLQocCy4LI846PaMscYMRYvt1wmk0RE9Pcjbq6qcstXlRiKllBEoQ90jZ-_pfZvLWCG6RR58SA0ZB9BSnhV5XhpqR7I1tC_fa3Iz1jn_l1_FuAUXlj_IWu00aVI8wLuIVnZtLuGKJ7PMrdG2b74ZQeODSSRlJero35xfie0NFMbe-Qm7LyBVSmQ0fHSs9QfZwbt1srv3FoD6KCsAfHAtGHpw74fP0r5Xvy7_gu5Wt9g3Q%3D%3D&ck=gmail&w=800&p=card
```

The div that holds the thumbnail is much more readable, it has an attribute download_url that looks like (again modified values):

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?ui=2&amp;ik=0219873534&amp;view=att&amp;th=137a1362746c7344&amp;attid=0.1&amp;disp=safe&amp;realattid=f_hyfu02x20&amp;zw
```

You can clearly see the thread id (parameter th) and attid (the part number for the attachment). So my guess is the JavaScript code transforms this attribute value into a data source reference that the thumbnailer understands. Now tracing through that minified JS code, that is another story...